# Setting up PHP Websockets

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, socket

I've written a game using PHP web sockets that runs well on my local development server.  I'm now attempting to run the web socket server on a non-local server, but my client JavaScript isn't able to connect.  I'm attempting this on a clean install of Ubuntu Server x64 - I've installed apache2, php5, and made sure the PHP socket extention is enabled; the server is working great for non-web socket purposes.

Is there a configuration setting I'm missing?  I've tried shutting down my firewall (via `ufw disable`).  Any clues would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here's the PHP library I'm using: https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat

I've realized that I actually won't be needing apache for what I'm doing - I only need the incoming requests to be accepted and interpreted by PHP.  Is there a way to ensure that all incoming requests are accessible to my PHP program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using apache module for websockets? There are quite a few PHP websocket servers implemented that you can try. Here are a few, http://www.spoutserver.com/ , http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/ , http://socketo.me/ . There are a couple more if you look around. If youp provide more details on your environment and implementation, help is easier.

UPDATE:

Change line 62 from in https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat/blob/master/server.php to

> $Server->wsStartServer('0.0.0.0', 9300);

or the IP to your external LAN IP and it should work. Restart the server.php after the change.

Comment: Is this basic test working? -- https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat/blob/master/README

Comment: Just tried it out - yes, it is working, as long as I'm accessing it from the server (my client is connecting to `127.0.0.1:9300`.)  Now I just need to figure out how to allow PHP access to the incoming requests...

Comment: Chida, you are my hero.

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can tell, the Apache packages provided by Ubuntu don't support websockets, and there is no package in Precise Pangolin that contains `mod_websocket.so` which is the [Apache module](https://github.com/disconnect/apache-websocket/blob/master/README.md) that provides support for websockets.  You'll need to install the module by hand, or change your production environment to use the same webserver as you're using in development.